# Always take newest version of a certain line in git regardless of merge conflicts

Tags: git, version-control, merge, timestamp

I have some files synced with git and they have time stamps. So if two people are working on the same file at more or less the same time they will invariably have some simple conflicts that can't be merged automatically. Is it possible to make git always take the newest version of a line in a given file no matter what? for the rest of the file, I need the git merging and conflict resolution to behave normally.

Comment: You can write your own merge driver, although this is not entirely trivial. Fortunately you can have your merge driver invoke `git merge-file` and see if the result has conflicts, and then decide whether you can resolve those conflicts using your method, but this is still going to be nontrivial. Note that files, in Git, do not *have* time stamps; only commits have time stamps. If some data within the file can be interpreted as a time stamp, you will have to do this interpreting yourself.

Comment: Thanks. My files themselves have timestamps in them. Each time the file is saved the new time is recorded in text at the top of the file.

Comment: @Alex You can also use **commit-msg hook** to detect the commit message contains `merge` sting, also get second parent branch name from commit message, and then compare the time stamps of the two parents, and finally use the latest version instead for this time merge commit.